# How to represent list of sparse features in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, sequence

I am trying to use `tensorflow.SequenceExample` to store my features for something like a question-answer system, which are described below.

Given a question text, for instance, "how far is home". I would like to treat it as a sequence, and represent each word using a sparse representation. This is not a one-hot encoding. Each word has multiple Boolean features.

```
how -> [ 1 0 0 0 1] -> [1,5]
far -> [ 0 1 1 0 0] -> [2,3]
is  -> [ 1 1 0 0 1] -> [1,2,5]
home-> [ 0 0 1 1 0] -> [3,4]
```

My text is now represented as: [[1,5],[2,3],[1,2,5],[3,4]]

Similarly, I have another text say `answer text` which has a similar representation of list-of-lists.

How do I write this in tensorflow's `TFRecord` format? I've tried it in the code below. What I know of to be an error is that I am sending an `int64list` to a function that expects only a single `int64` value.

Did anyone have any success in representing such data?

```
import tensorflow as tf


example = {

    'query': [[123, 543, 234, 2322],
              [133, 243, 233, 256, 4332],
              [232, 356, 632],
              [153, 143, 231, 456]],
    'document': [[1156, 12322],
                 [2133, 14332],
                 [1143, 1343, 1232, 1356, 1632],
                 [1153, 1143]],
    'label': 1
}

tmp_filename = 'tf.tmp'


def make_example(example):
    """
    Makes a single example from Python lists that follows the
    format of tf.train.SequenceExample.
    """
    query_features = example['query']
    keyword_features = example['document']
    example_sequence = tf.train.SequenceExample()

    example_sequence.context.feature["query_length"].int64_list.value.append(len(query_features))
    example_sequence.context.feature["keyword_length"].int64_list.value.append(len(keyword_features))

    query = example_sequence.feature_lists.feature_list["query"]
    document = example_sequence.feature_lists.feature_list["document"]

    for feat in query_features:
        print("Appending: ", feat)
        #query.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(feat)
        query.feature.add().list.value.append(feat)


    for feat in keyword_features:
        document.feature.add().int64_list.value.append(feat)

    return example_sequence


# Write all examples into a TFRecords file
def save_tf(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(fp.name)

        ex = make_example(example)
        writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
        writer.close()


#
def read_and_decode_single_example(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],
                                                    num_epochs=None)

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    context_features = {
        "length": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    sequence_features = {

        "query": tf.VarLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
        "document": tf.VarLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    return serialized_example, context_features, sequence_feature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the best way to go with encoding arrays is to use numpy's [`tostring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) to extract the raw bytes. When reading in the dataset you can then use TensorFlow's [`decode_raw`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw).

The following should suffice for your encoding:

```
for feat in query_features:
    print("Appending: ", feat)
    raw_feat = np.array(feat, dtype=np.int64).tostring()
    query.feature.add().bytes_list.value.append(raw_feat)

for feat in keyword_features:
    raw_feat = np.array(feat, dtype=np.int64).tostring()
    document.feature.add().bytes_list.value.append(raw_feat)
```

Note that you have to make sure that you use the same data type on the other side when decoding (`tf.int64` in this example) or you will end up with gibberish.

Comment: That sounds great. Can I give it to keras.train or tf.train methods and the data gets parsed accordingly? Sorry if this question is not clear, please ask if you need any clarifications.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The above code is to replace a code snippet in the code you posted. This should be inserted into the `make_example` function.

Comment: I get that. Should have been clearer about the requirement. I’ll accept the answer anyway as is, but just want to know if data serialized to string can be used in tf training functions

Comment: After toying with deserializing, you'll have to use `np.fromstring` because `decode_raw` doesn't play well with variable size input. If you need to use it then you could zero pad (or -1 if zero is a valid element) your data to be the same length.

Comment: Great. Will try it out. Thanks